# Kamailio and a connection to the PSTN via SIP

Tags: sip, voip, kamailio, inbound

I think about the following setup, but I do not know how to connect the main parts.

One the one side there is a Kamailio SIP server. This server provides VoIP connectivity within a certain network (non public intranet).

On the other side there is a SIP provider. This provider provides a single telephone number from the PSTN. Let's say the number is 0034-443322.

Both components are working fine so far.

I want to use that number as a dial-in to my private network. A user with number 8282 in my network should be reachable via 0034-443322-8282 from the outside world. Outgoing calls aren't necessary.

How to reach my goal? I don't know what to look for :/ Any ideas are very welcome :)

kind regards
K.A.

Answer (score 1):

If your PSTN gateway can be reached by dialing the full number (including the extension), simply let the gateway forward every incoming call to your Kamailio instance which will forward the call to the appropriate user. For that, you need to create your users (known as subscribers in Kamailio) and they need to register to your Kamailio instance so that they can receive incoming calls. Regarding mapping extensions to users, you can simply let the extension be the username; or you can add extensions as aliases of the subscribers.